# Why can't you fit a quasi-Poisson in `lme4`?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, negative-binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

Is there a philosophical reason why lme4 does not allow you to fit a quasi-Poisson model while it *will* allow you to fit a negative binomial model? I do not see any reason why any glmm package should exclude one of these options. In fact, it seems quite inappropriate to allow only one of these options as they are not equivalent (but are often treated as equivalent) and limiting a package to one or the other will invite users to inappropriately substitute one for the other.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that it is, in essence, a philosophical statistical question and not a programming question.

Comment: You realize that it is not only a matter of "not allow[ing]" but also a matter of having the resources to implement it? From the [FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html): "Quasi- was deemed unreliable in lme4, and is no longer available. (Part of the problem was questionable numerical results in some cases; the other problem was that [Douglas Bates] felt that he did not have a sufficiently good understanding of the theoretical framework that would explain what the algorithm was actually estimating in this case.)"